# Does ticket re-issue result in new PNR or New ticket number

Tags: air-travel, tickets, international-travel, gds

I was trying to see if a ticket is re-issued, will the old PNR and ticket number get cancelled, then a new one will be allocated?

[Assume changes [ reissue] are done by agents using GDS]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a reissued ticket (i.e. not a revalidated ticket), a totally new ticket will be issued. If the ticket is part of a booklet (i.e., there are more than four flights), all the conjoined tickets in the booklet will be reissued as well.

A ticket number cannot be re-used, they are globally unique, and the number is used for accounting and auditing purposes. In a revalidation, certain fields in a ticket can be altered, but that is different to a reissue. In the old
days a revalidation was done with a sticker that covered up certain parts of the old ticket; the same limitations are applied
to electronic ticketing.

Almost always the PNR will be unchanged, but that is not required. The ticket and PNR are unrelated concepts.